# Setting Azure Metric Namespace value when using OpenTelemetry Exporter

Tags: azure, .net-core, open-telemetry, azure-monitoring

I've recently switched to using the OpenTelemetry .NET library for instrumenting my application and pushing those metrics to Azure Monitor/Application Insights with the [Azure Exporter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter). Previously I've used the this [Application Insights Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/) provided by Microsoft. As part of that library it is possible to set a namespace for the metrics by using a metric identifier e.g.

```
telemetryClient.GetMetric(new MetricIdentifier("MyMetricNamespace", "MyMetricName")).TrackValue(duration)
```

This had the advantage that in Azure when viewing the metrics they would be grouped together by their namespace making it easier to find that metric I need.

[image: Entering metric in Azure]

When using the OpenTelemetry library I cannot find a way to set this namespace and instead they are just stored under the generic `azure.applicationinsights` namespace.

[image: Azure metrics generic namespace]

Is there a way of setting the metric namespace value when using the Azure Monitor Exporter?